# Changing hierarchy structure while keeping nested relationships

Tags: sysml, magic-draw

This is just an example, but lets say I have an IBD of context “vehicle”. In the IBD I have part properties “vehicle.car.navSystem” with proxy ports and connectors to “vehicle.car.navSystem.gps” and “vehicle.car.navSystem.display”.

I want to change the hierarchy “vehicle.car.navSystem” to “vehicle.truck.navSystem”, where the “truck” block already exists, but I want to keep both blocks “truck” and “car”, without having to manually remake all of the connectors and instances of part properties. So I’d end up with “vehicle.car” without the part “navSystem”, and in the IBD of “vehicle” I’d have “vehicle.truck.navSystem” with connectors to “vehicle.truck.navSystem.gps” and “vehicle.truck.navSystem.display”.

I hope that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your example. Why would a Vehicle have a part car? A Car _is a_ Vehicle! A Truck is also a Vehicle. You don't say anything about connectors belonging to the Vehicle, the Car or the Truck. Instead it seems the NavSystem has ports, two parts, the GPS and the Display, and connectors between the parts and the ports. You can make the NavSystem a part of a Vehicle and let the Car and the Truck inherit it via specialization. A tool will be able to display the inner parts of the inherited NavSystem in an ibd of a Car or a Truck. You can then connect its ports to Car or Truck parts.

Comment: @Axel Scheithauer,  That was just an example and was not intended to make sense. Although I guess ‘vehicle system’ would be more accurate. The problem is we’re changing the structure of our model to align with a new WBS so some subsystems have to change their parents. When we do that, the connectors for the ibd’s for all the subsystems’ components break and we have to remake all of them.

Comment: The nested relationships belong to the subsystem (NavSystem in your example). They don't break by moving the subsystem to another system (e.g. Truck). If they do in your tool, maybe it is a bug. Or are you talking about relationships from parts you don't mention in your example directly to nested parts of the NavSystem? If you move those parts together with the navSystem-part, your tool should move the connectors as well. If it can't do that, it would be disqualified as a systems engineering tool. Try using intermediary ports instead of direct connectors. A diagram would help the discussion.

Comment: I just noticed the tag [magic-draw]. That is the tool I'm using. I checked it with it, and it works. I used drag and drop in the ibd to move the parts. Doing it right in the containment tree should also work. Maybe the problem is, that diagrams are not automatically updated to show all connectors. This is by design, because I as a modeler want to decide, which connectors to show. In order to display all paths, there is a context menu entry.